# Drawing tiles using UIImage or use buttons?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiimageview

I'm new to IOS development, and want to create something with tiles similar to what you see here. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7giaN5T7ww

Since I'm a beginner, I see myself placing a bunch of buttons on the screen and labeling them to how I see fit. Then figuring out how to move multiple "buttons" at once. I was wondering how you think the tiles are created in this program? If not done by a bunch of buttons, could someone show me code to draw a tile with dimensions of 48x48 pixels, then place a letter on the tile?

Also, if you could point me to some helpful resources that would help me develop something along the lines of a project like this, I would most appreciate it. I'm excited and very motivated to learn and master IOS development and consequently objective-c.

My knowledge is limited to what I've learned by watching and coding along to these two YouTube playlists:

http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston#p/c/640F44F1C97BA581
http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston#p/c/53038489615793F7

They've been extremely helpful in helping me understand the basics of Objective-C and Iphone development. Unfortunately, it didn't get into drawing and manipulating objects on the screen.

Thanks in advance for your help. I've found this site and its users quite helpful already. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kind of similar apps in the app store and I used in one case `UILabel`s and in another case `UIView`s with `UIImageView`s as subviews. The movement of the labels I have implemented with the methods `touchesBegan:withEvent`, `touchesMoved:withEvent` and `touchesEnded:withEvent`.

Comment: Thanks for your response @dasdom. Could you point me to your applications in the store where you've used them? And which app used the UIImageView and which used UILabels?

Are you saying that you can create a UIlabel that looks like a tile? Or do you need to draw the tile then place the label inside?

Comment: Sorry, the one with the label isn't in the store yet. I am still working on that. The app using the UIView is PhyLer and MathLer. If you like I give you a promo code.

Comment: @dasdin, a promo code would be awesome. I'd really appreciate that. In this screenshot of your app: http://i.imgur.com/k055a.jpg, the dark gray area above your tiles. What is that? Is that a separate "view" or "view controller"? Thank you for your time. I think it's awesome that you're developing educational programs. That's what I'm wanting to get into myself.

Comment: The dark gray area is a view. Can you post you mail address here? Or write me your mail address to dom (at) dasdom (dot) de.